# Does the T-1000 know that the "big guy on a bike" is a T-800 before he meets him?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In the movie [*Terminator 2: Judgement Day* (1991)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103064/), after the terminators had arrived from the future to 1995, they are both trying to acquire John Connor.

The T-1000 arrives at John Connor's address and interrogates his foster parents:

> **Janelle:** There was a guy here this morning looking for him too.
>   **Todd:** Yeah, a big guy on a bike, has that got something to do with this?
>   **T-1000:** No. I wouldn't worry about him.

At this point, is there any evidence that the T-1000 knows that this "big guy" is a T-800, or is he just confident he can handle anyone else aiming to acquire John?

Comment: Well, I guess they _are_ sent from the future, so to them this has already happened so of course they know about each other. Except of course that the future changes so Cyberdyne doesn't exist so it doesn't happen. But then, if it doesn't happen there is no-one to stop Cyberdyne from existing so... oh no my brain is leaking out my ears...

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: I guess the "rationale" is that for this t1000, that past is yet unmodified and indeed the t800-as-a-biker is known to the t1000. In the future of that same t1000 the "past" will be changed, but it hasn't occured yet in this t1000 timeline. or something.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland "I suggest you don't worry about this sort of thing and... just enjoy yourself." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SPk3NjYfmQ

Comment: From T1000 point of view, there is no coincidence, Someone were  asking about him this morning. _..Analysing new element.._ Best case senario: No worry, I'm a T1000.  Worse case senario: No worry, I'm a T1000. From there to realising it's the T800, it's just about math with weighting based on the dangerousness. As every other possibility are irrevelant.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

## Yes

[**The script**](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html) confirms that, at the very least, the T-1000 (in the script as "Officer X") has a very good idea as to who the previous visitor was...

> ```
>                             JANELLE
>             There was a guy here this morning asking about
>             him, too.
>
>                            TODD
>             Yeah, big guy.  On a bike.  Has that got
>             something to do with it?
>
>    Officer X registers the significance of that.  He realizes who the
>     big guy must be.  He smiles.  Reassuringly shakes his head no.
> ```

It seems implicit from this that the T-1000 was fully aware of the previous Terminator.

Comment: Nice find! I was going to add more speculation to my answer as per popular request

Comment: @Luciano Feel free to still do that. Improving answers is never a bad idea.

Comment: "He's a good-looking boy. Do you mind if I keep this picture?"

Comment: The T-1000 human mimicry is excellent, it even betrays what a human playing a T-1000 _would_ unconsciously let slip in that situation through facial expressions. Probably an artifact of Google's "Mimi-Cry" neural tracking project of 2020, see the paper "Tensorflow makes Mimi Cry: Artifacts in tensorflow system tracking human neural operations, Google Brain, [International Journal of Cognitive Informatics and Natural Intelligence , Volume 14, Issue 3, 2020]"

Comment: In conversation, someone pointed out that the T-1000 as a police officer, would be privileged to police information, such as reports of a large, naked man having messed up a biker bar single handedly, followed by subsequent other reports. It's an inference, rather than evidence, but goes to explain that the T-1000 could have information to infer that it could be a T-800 looking for John.

Comment: @StuperUser or at the very least, someone from the future.

Answer (score 20):

There's nothing that can prove that, it's never shown to us in the movie. Although:

- He could have figured out: "If I'm here and the resistance sent someone too, this time it might be a captured T-800 adapted to protect John Connor".
- [The script shows](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html) that during the interview with Connor's foster parents "He (the T-1000) realizes who the big guy must be." Perhaps he just realized that it was Connor's protector, another human sent from the future, he might still not be aware the resistance had a T-800 on their side.

Answer (score 3):

The T-1000 didn't know it was a Terminator. He emptied the gun clip at him on first encounter. If he already knew, then he'd knew the T-800 was bulletproof and wouldn't bother firing. And no he was shooting for the Terminator as he shielded John, not directly at John. If the T-1000 knew it was a Terminator, he wouldn't have emptied his bullets in vain at a bodyshielding T-800 in order to score a hit at Connor. That would be inefficient for a programming of a killing machine.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put: NO.

> T-1000: Could I speak with him, please?
>
> Stepdad: You could if he were here.  Took off on his bike this morning, so he could be anywhere.
>
> ...
>
> Stepmom: There was a guy here this morning looking for him too.
>
> Stepdad: yeah, a big guy on a bike.  Does that got something to do
> with this?

John Connor left on his **bike**. Someone else was looking for him, a big guy on a **bike**. Now, to me, that says nothing about a T-800. Coulda been some bully, or co-conspirator, or playmate they weren't even aware of. They were both on "bikes", how could anyone/anything summize who the "big guy on a bike" is?

Comment: "_to me it says nothing about a T-800_" but you're also not a T-1000 sent from the future, are you? :)

Comment: How do you know that? ;)

Comment: No. I wouldn't worry about Johnny Bones.

Answer (score -4):

The T1000 absolutely knows about the T800 and feels it has no cause for concern, the T1000 past includes information about an "inferior" model being sent before it... the T800... so it thinks "meh - the T800 is going to be no problems"

Comment: "the T1000 past includes information about an "inferior" model being sent before it" - could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score -5):

Yes, because Arnold is "model 101" of the T-800 series (as opposed to "unknown-model" entering the tunnel in the original film, or "unknown-model" in the second sequel, but sure enough they'd have some identification number as well, only we don't know it).

So, it's pretty obvious to anyone having had access to the model series, including the T-1000.

In one of the later sequels, toward they pull one of many identical model 101s out of a breeding thing, too. Which, unmistakingly, is a CGI rig of young Arnold.

Comment: How does the specific sub-model number tie to the T-1000 knowing that some big guy was a T-800?

Comment: Hi Damon, you're right that once he sees the T-800 in the mall, he'd be able to identify him based on the model 101 skinjob, but the question was about whether the T-1000 knew before they met and before he would have seen him.

Comment: I like this answer because it picks up on the fact that since the T-1000 is also a machine he very likely has functionality that allows him to easily detect other machines (so even if the T-800 had different skin he could likely still detect he was a machine so as to avoid attacking machines that were working as infiltrates to the human resistance groups). **However** it does miss out on the crucial point that the T-1000 and T-800 have had no contact at all by this point in the film which is likely why you are attracting downvotes. Shame, as it would have been a plausible answer otherwise!

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: Well, the whole point is that "model 101" is "Arnold Skin". It is the skin that is shown in the original movie, it is the one you see (and explicitly stated being model 101) in T2, and it is the one they activate (from an alcove with several identical models/skins) at the beginning of "Genysis", and which is also seen towards the end of "Salvation".  So **certainly** if you know what "model 101" is (and the T-1000 likely would) then you can recognize its characteristic form (with otherwise identical robot underneath) at first sight.

Comment: Yeah dude I got that, I was just extrapolating out that by time they got to T-1000 they probably had as many different models with different skins (not to mention ones like the T-1000 that can change 'skin') that they would have likely built in the functionality that allowed identification of fellow machines not based on visual cues alone.